# How to create a discord.js command without a prefix?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create a bot that will say goodnight back to "goodnight" as a side command, but I don't know how to do a single command without a prefix.  I found a post on this that had a good answer and I applied it, but now I am having a different problem.

Here is my `bot.js` main file:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = 'm!';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Meonkl is Online!');
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",  //You can show online, idle....
    });
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command == 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('pong').execute(message, args);
    }else if(message.content.toLowerCase() == 'goodnight'){
        client.commands.get('goodnight').execute(message, args);
    }

    console.log(message.member, message, args);
});

client.login('');
```

I suspect the problem is this line, `if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;` but I cannot take it out and break my regular commands.

I am unsure what to do, or if there is a clean solution.

Comment: Why not just alter the ocndition so that if the message *doesn't* start with the prefix, the message content can only be "goodnight"?

Comment: @esqew How would I do that?

Comment: `if (/* starts with prefix? */) { /* command handling */ } else if (/* says goodnight */) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: The bot originally listens to all messages, the prefix is what other apps implement to distinguish it so it doesn't conflict for one another. If you don't want any prefix, simply don't implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your message handler function (`if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return`) will not let you execute anything else if the incoming message doesn't start with the `prefix`. You can remove the `!message.content.startsWith(prefix)` part:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('pong').execute(message, args);
    } else if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'goodnight') {
        client.commands.get('goodnight').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

Or you can let through some unprefixed commands; just use an array to store these and check if the message is included in this array. Check the snippet below:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const unprefixedCommands = ['goodnight', 'morning'];
  const isUnprefixedCommand = unprefixedCommands.includes(message.content.toLowerCase());

  if (!isUnprefixedCommand && !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  let args;
  let command;

  if (isUnprefixedCommand) {
    // don't remove the prefix from the message
    // although it will be an array with the command only
    // not sure how you want to use it :)
    args = message.content.split(/ +/);
    // the command is the message content itself
    // this way both "!goodnight" and "goodnight" will work
    command = message.content.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    // it's the same as before
    args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  }

  if (command === 'ping') {
    client.commands.get('pong').execute(message, args);
  } else if (command === 'goodnight') {
    client.commands.get('goodnight').execute(message, args);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but for messages without commands, i just start a new line of code and just type, for example,

```
client.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.content === 'Goodnight!') {
msg.reply('Pingas!');
}
});
```

Comment: If you'd like to do it without replying, instead of "msg.reply", you can type "msg.channel.send". hope this helps.